# Using TabControl for Navigation in MVVMLight Silverlight4

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabcontrol, mvvm-light

Greetings -

I'd like to demonstrate Tab Control functionality in my MVVM Light application. I'm using an EventToCommand/RelayCommand to load an instance of a view: DisplayWorkOrderView, when I click on the header marked "Work Order".

The view loads into the Content property of a frame I have inside each of the tabItems. The only problem I have is my tab control completely disappears when this happens! The view lodas into the frame no problem, but for whatever reason that frame control takes over the entire window.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setup on a tabcontrol is not real straight forward, you actually have to put what you want for the content of the tab inside the content part of the header tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293684/tabcontrol-styling-in-wpf

the styling will be the same for silverlight